# Are multiline matches supported in lineinfile?

Tags: regex, ansible

I would like to match (and remove or replace with one commented line) a block of lines:

```
daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.err;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

I tried to match them in `lineinfile` with `daemon(?:.|\n)*xconsole` but the match does not seem to happen: a replacement line is added but the old line remains:

```
  - name: remove xconsole from rsyslog.conf
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/rsyslog.conf
      regexp: daemon(?:.|\n)*xconsole
      state: absent
      # also tried to add the next line to replace with a comment
      #line: "# removed by ansible"
```

**Are such blocks supported?**

Note: I know about `blockinfile` which is great to manage the addition/removal of delimited blocks. I do not believe that they work with non-ansible-inserted blocks (matched though a regex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `lineinfile` search expression line by line, see [module's source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/files/lineinfile.py#L220).

If you need to remove/replace text, use `replace` module – it use multiline regex, e.g.:

```
 - name: remove xconsole from rsyslog.conf
    replace:
      dest: /etc/rsyslog.conf
      # ensure regex is lazy!
      regexp: daemon[\S\s]*?xconsole
      replace: "# removed by ansible"
```